# Open NERDTree when vim is opened without args, but not with -

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I would like NERDTree to open on startup when I start vim without any arguments, but I don't want it to open when I use `foo | vim -`

I have `autocmd VimEnter * if !argc() | NERDTree | endif` in my vimrc already, but of course this still opens it with `vim -`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `StdinReadPre` event to set a flag to detect this:

```
autocmd StdinReadPre * let g:isReadingFromStdin = 1
autocmd VimEnter * if !argc() && !exists('g:isReadingFromStdin') | NERDTree | endif
```